# SSRS Report Between Two Dates

Tags: reporting-services

I'm using SSRS reports in SharePoint 2010.  I need to get my report to generate information in between the StartDate and StopDate.  Currently it only gives me what was entered on the exact stop date.  Where do I put the >= and how?  I've tried putting it in the filter, but I get an error that says I can't mix fields and parameters.  I have parameters so the user can enter the dates and I have Start_Date and Stop_Date fields.

I apologize in advance.  I'm a newbie to SSRS Reporting.

```
<FieldRef Name="Drug_x0020_Name" />
<FieldRef Name="Inmate_x0020_Last_x0020_Name" />
<FieldRef Name="Start_x0020_Date" />
<FieldRef Name="Stop_x0020_Date" />
<FieldRef Name="ID" />
<FieldRef Name="DiscontinuedDate" />
<FieldRef Name="Prescription_x0020_Type" />
<FieldRef Name="Created" />
<FieldRef Name="InmateID" />
<FieldRef Name="Inmate_x0020_First_x0020_Name" />
<FieldRef Name="Ordered_x0020_Date" />
<FieldRef Name="DrugClassification" />
```

Thanks in advance!
Tara

Comment: If you could edit your question to include the SQL for you report, that would allow us to help you more quickly.

Comment: I hope that's what you were looking for. :)

Comment: Not quite. What I am looking for is the SQL code, or the query, for the main dataset in the report. You can see it by right-clicking on the dataset in the report designer and choosing Query... The code usually starts with the clause `SELECT ... `. I would need to see all of that.

Comment: I don't see the SQL code.  All I see is the query that I posted. If I open it in Visual Studio I can pull this out. <Field Name="Start_Date">
          <DataField>Start_x0020_Date</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.DateTime</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="Prescription_Type">
          <DataField>Prescription_x0020_Type</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="Stop_Date">
          <DataField>Stop_x0020_Date</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.DateTime</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>

Comment: These are the parameters I have, I just need the start date to be less than or equal to and the stop date to be greater than or equal to.                           <FilterExpression>=Fields!Start_Date.Value</FilterExpression>
          <Operator>Between</Operator>
          <FilterValues>
            <FilterValue>=Parameters!StartDate.Value</FilterValue>
            <FilterValue>=Parameters!StopDate.Value</FilterValue>
          </FilterValues>
        </Filter>

Comment: I actually which it was in SQL.  I can get around better in it. :)

Comment: Are you editing the RDL directly, without the report designer? If so, why? You can download SQL Server Database Tools to get the designer if you do not have it.

Comment: No, I'm using SQL Server Report Builder 3.0.  Same thing I used to do all the other filters and queries.

Comment: Got it. I am going to post an answer here is a minute. Hopefully it helps you out.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what a filter should look like in the designer. I don't use Report Builder, but it should have something similar as far as a tablix properties dialog. *Of course*, the expression field and parameter names will be different for you. Usually a `Between` filter is inclusive of the beginning and end date, so this may give similar results to what you are getting now. You can always remove the second part of the filter if you want to get everything after the start date.

[image: Tablix Properties]

If you want to overwrite the Filter right in the RDL, here is what that looks like based on the image above. I have changed the names to match what you have posted in the comments.

```
<Filters>
    <Filter>
    <FilterExpression>=Fields!Start_Date.Value</FilterExpression>
    <Operator>GreaterThanOrEqual</Operator>
    <FilterValues>
        <FilterValue>=Parameters!StartDate.Value</FilterValue>
    </FilterValues>
    </Filter>
    <Filter>
    <FilterExpression>=Fields!Start_Date.Value</FilterExpression>
    <Operator>LessThanOrEqual</Operator>
    <FilterValues>
        <FilterValue>=Parameters!StopDate.Value</FilterValue>
    </FilterValues>
    </Filter>
</Filters>
```

Editing RDL directly is not the best way to go about this, but you can do it. Just be careful, is all.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks so much for all of your help.  I had tried that query, but for some reason would not work.  Logically it should.  I ended up getting this to work by:

Comment: Ahh well, it won't let me post the snip. I put the start and stop date in the same filter line and used Between.  The problem with that is I don't get the first and last date.  I'm about to pull my hair out so I guess I'll just have to have the users put the date before and the date after of what they really want to see.

Comment: That should work, them changing the date. Chances are the dates in the data also include the time, and the date from the parameters do not have a time on them. That can cause the query to exclude a full day on the end. I usually change the SQL to make up for that. If you can change the default end date to whatever it is now, plus one day, that may make it a little easier on the end user.